# Creative CMV files converter

Tags: linux, video, conversion, creative

Is there any application in linux-land that can encode files into the Creative's own .cmv?
I tried their C.Centrale, but it doesn't seem to work well through Wine.

I need one that will work with `Zen MX`, which doesn't accept the original xvids / wmvs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the description which Samy pointed out (thanks!), I created an encoder script myself. The project lives at http://bitbucket.org/viraptor/cmv_encoder/wiki/Home

Answer (score 2):

I would be very interested too butnobody seems to have the answer. The CMV format is a little bit described here [link](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=CMV)

it seems to look a lot like MJpeg format...

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't find that description myself - will try to hack on it later...

Comment: Thanks again! I could create my own encoder thanks to this description - http://bitbucket.org/viraptor/cmv_encoder/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the same format, but this guy made a script for converting movies for creative Zen Vision:M, it might be worth a shot http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=539398

Comment: Unfortunately no - it would work for other zens, but the mx version is 'different' and doesn't accept normal xvids.